# Angular Materials - md-datepicker display issue on large browser

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

Im using `md-datepicker` in my app but it doesnt display right for larger browser widths. Seems to only work as intended for small and x-small widths. Please see screenshot attached.

This happens on Chrome and Safari.

HTML:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="data" md-placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></md-datepicker>
```

[image]

Ive tried narrowing down the problem using inspector and it may have something to do with the `left` property value on the `md-datepicker-calendar-pane` class, but Im not sure.

[image]

Comment: did you found the solution?

Comment: yes i did eventually find the right css settings to resolve but opted for a custom built datepicker ultimately. thank you

Comment: Can you share that ?

Comment: I don't have access to that codebase anymore. I think it was basically a inline-block style on some parent container

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue. table width was set globally as 100% in an app. The following fixed it:

```
.md-datepicker-calendar-pane table {
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your css

I had something like this which was causing your exact issue

table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}

Comment: I just had this issue and it turned out to be existing styles on td and table tags.